# .htaccess URL redirect for sub domain and query pattern

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I need to redirect via .htaccess such an URL:

```
mydomain.com/?c=*
```

into

```
sub.mydomain.com/?c=*
```

For example:

must be redirected

```
mydomain.com/?c=123&a=1&b=2
```

into

```
sub.mydomain.com/?c=123&a=1&b=2
```

must not be redirected neither

```
mydomain.com/folder/?c=123&a=1&b=2
```

nor

```
mydomain.com/?cb=123&a=1&b=2
```

My Apache ver 2.4.29.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following rule

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^c=.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ http://sub.domain.com/ [L,R]
```